# Reduce the size of the block of the title

Tags: spacing, posters, tikzposter

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym,url}

\title{\LARGE{A note on the generalized maximal numerical range of operators}}
\author{xxxxxxxxx (joint work with xxxxxxxxxx and xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)}
\institute{Faculty of Science and xxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\insertlogoi[2][]{\def\@insertlogoi{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\newcommand\insertlogoii[2][]{\def\@insertlogoii{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\newlength\LogoSep
\setlength\LogoSep{0pt}

\insertlogoi[width=10cm]{example-image-a}
\insertlogoii[width=10cm]{example-image-b}

\renewcommand\maketitle[1][]{  % #1 keys
    \normalsize
    \setkeys{title}{#1}
    % Title dummy to get title height
    \node[transparent,inner sep=\TP@titleinnersep, line width=\TP@titlelinewidth, anchor=north, minimum width=\TP@visibletextwidth-2\TP@titleinnersep]
        (TP@title) at ($(0, 0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace)$) {\parbox{\TP@titlewidth-2\TP@titleinnersep}{\TP@maketitle}};
    \draw let \p1 = ($(TP@title.north)-(TP@title.south)$) in node {
        \setlength{\TP@titleheight}{\y1}
        \setlength{\titleheight}{\y1}
        \global\TP@titleheight=\TP@titleheight
        \global\titleheight=\titleheight
    };

    % Compute title position
    \setlength{\titleposleft}{-0.5\titlewidth}
    \setlength{\titleposright}{\titleposleft+\titlewidth}
    \setlength{\titlepostop}{0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace}
    \setlength{\titleposbottom}{\titlepostop-\titleheight}

    % Title style (background)
    \TP@titlestyle

    % Title node
    \node[inner sep=\TP@titleinnersep, line width=\TP@titlelinewidth, anchor=north, minimum width=\TP@visibletextwidth-2\TP@titleinnersep]
        at (0,0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace)
        (title)
        {\parbox{\TP@titlewidth-2\TP@titleinnersep}{\TP@maketitle}};

    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=west]
      at ([xshift=-\LogoSep]title.west)
      {\@insertlogoi};

    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=east]
      at ([xshift=\LogoSep]title.east)
      {\@insertlogoii};

    % Settings for blocks
    \normalsize
    \setlength{\TP@blocktop}{\titleposbottom-\TP@titletoblockverticalspace}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

 % Title block with title, author, logo, etc.
\maketitle
 \block{Basic Block}{Text}
 \begin{columns}

 % FIRST column
\column{0.6}% Width set relative to text width

\block{Large Column}{Text\\Text\\Text Text Text}
\note{Note with default behavior}
\note[targetoffsetx=12cm, targetoffsety=-1cm, angle=20, rotate=25]
{Note \\ offset and rotated}

 % First column - second block
\block{Block titles with enough text will automatically obey spacing requirements }
{Text\\Text}

 % First column - third block
\block{Sample Block 4}{T\\E\\S\\T}

 % SECOND column
\column{0.4}
 %Second column with first block's top edge aligned with with previous column's top.

 % Second column - first block
\block[titleleft]{Smaller Column}{Test}

 % Second column - second block
\block[titlewidthscale=0.6, bodywidthscale=0.8]
{Variable width title}{Block with smaller width.}

 % Second column - third block
\block{}{Block with no title}

 % Second column - A collection of blocks in subcolumn environment.
\begin{subcolumns}
    \subcolumn{0.27} \block{1}{First block.} \block{2}{Second block}
    \subcolumn{0.4} \block{Sub-columns}{Sample subblocks\\Second subcolumn}
    \subcolumn{0.33} \block{4}{Fourth} \block{}{Final Subcolumn block}
\end{subcolumns}

 % Bottomblock
\block{Final Block in column}{
    Sample block.
}
\end{columns}
\block[titleleft, titleoffsetx=2em, titleoffsety=1em, bodyoffsetx=2em,%
 bodyoffsety=-2cm, roundedcorners=10, linewidth=0mm, titlewidthscale=0.7,%
 bodywidthscale=0.9, bodyverticalshift=2cm, titleright]
{Block outside of Columns}{Along with several options enabled}

\end{document}
```

I want to reduce the size of the block of the title since I want to insert two logo

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Define and apply a new title style with the appropriate width.

(2) Insert the (long) title in a `parbox`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym,url}

%*************************************************  added
\definetitlestyle{NewDefault}{% adjust width <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    width=500mm, roundedcorners=30, linewidth=0.4cm, innersep=1cm,
    titletotopverticalspace=15mm, titletoblockverticalspace=20mm,
    titlegraphictotitledistance=10pt, titletextscale=1
}{%
    \begin{scope}[line width=\titlelinewidth, rounded corners=\titleroundedcorners]
        \draw[color=framecolor, fill=titlebgcolor]%
        (\titleposleft,\titleposbottom) rectangle (\titleposright,\titlepostop);
    \end{scope}
}

\usetitlestyle{NewDefault}
%*************************************************

\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering \LARGE{A note on the generalized maximal numerical range  of operators}}} % changed <<<<<<

\author{xxxxxxxxx (joint work with xxxxxxxxxx and xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)}
\institute{Faculty of Science and xxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\insertlogoi[2][]{\def\@insertlogoi{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\newcommand\insertlogoii[2][]{\def\@insertlogoii{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\newlength\LogoSep
\setlength\LogoSep{0pt}

\insertlogoi[width=10cm]{example-image-a}
\insertlogoii[width=10cm]{example-image-b}

\renewcommand\maketitle[1][]{  % #1 keys
    \normalsize
    \setkeys{title}{#1}
    % Title dummy to get title height
    \node[transparent,inner sep=\TP@titleinnersep, line width=\TP@titlelinewidth, anchor=north, minimum width=\TP@visibletextwidth-2\TP@titleinnersep]
    (TP@title) at ($(0, 0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace)$) {\parbox{\TP@titlewidth-2\TP@titleinnersep}{\TP@maketitle}};
    \draw let \p1 = ($(TP@title.north)-(TP@title.south)$) in node {
        \setlength{\TP@titleheight}{\y1}
        \setlength{\titleheight}{\y1}
        \global\TP@titleheight=\TP@titleheight
        \global\titleheight=\titleheight
    };
    
    % Compute title position
    \setlength{\titleposleft}{-0.5\titlewidth}
    \setlength{\titleposright}{\titleposleft+\titlewidth}
    \setlength{\titlepostop}{0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace}
    \setlength{\titleposbottom}{\titlepostop-\titleheight}
    
    % Title style (background)
    \TP@titlestyle
    
    % Title node
    \node[inner sep=\TP@titleinnersep, line width=\TP@titlelinewidth, anchor=north, minimum width=\TP@visibletextwidth-2\TP@titleinnersep]
    at (0,0.5\textheight-\TP@titletotopverticalspace)
    (title)
    {\parbox{\TP@titlewidth-2\TP@titleinnersep}{\TP@maketitle}};
    
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=west]
    at ([xshift=-\LogoSep]title.west)
    {\@insertlogoi};
    
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=east]
    at ([xshift=\LogoSep]title.east)
    {\@insertlogoii};
    
    % Settings for blocks
    \normalsize
    \setlength{\TP@blocktop}{\titleposbottom-\TP@titletoblockverticalspace}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
    % Title block with title, author, logo, etc.
    \maketitle
    \block{Basic Block}{Text}
    \begin{columns}
        
        % FIRST column
        \column{0.6}% Width set relative to text width
        
        \block{Large Column}{Text\\Text\\Text Text Text}
        \note{Note with default behavior}
        \note[targetoffsetx=12cm, targetoffsety=-1cm, angle=20, rotate=25]
        {Note \\ offset and rotated}
        
        % First column - second block
        \block{Block titles with enough text will automatically obey spacing requirements }
        {Text\\Text}
        
        % First column - third block
        \block{Sample Block 4}{T\\E\\S\\T}
        
        % SECOND column
        \column{0.4}
        %Second column with first block's top edge aligned with with previous column's top.
        
        % Second column - first block
        \block[titleleft]{Smaller Column}{Test}
        
        % Second column - second block
        \block[titlewidthscale=0.6, bodywidthscale=0.8]
        {Variable width title}{Block with smaller width.}
        
        % Second column - third block
        \block{}{Block with no title}
        
        % Second column - A collection of blocks in subcolumn environment.
        \begin{subcolumns}
            \subcolumn{0.27} \block{1}{First block.} \block{2}{Second block}
            \subcolumn{0.4} \block{Sub-columns}{Sample subblocks\\Second subcolumn}
            \subcolumn{0.33} \block{4}{Fourth} \block{}{Final Subcolumn block}
        \end{subcolumns}
        
        % Bottomblock
        \block{Final Block in column}{
            Sample block.
        }
    \end{columns}
    \block[titleleft, titleoffsetx=2em, titleoffsety=1em, bodyoffsetx=2em,%
    bodyoffsety=-2cm, roundedcorners=10, linewidth=0mm, titlewidthscale=0.7,%
    bodywidthscale=0.9, bodyverticalshift=2cm, titleright]
    {Block outside of Columns}{Along with several options enabled}
    
\end{document}
```